# MBR2GPT Disk layout validation failed with multiple drives

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, mbr, gpt

I'm currently trying to convert all my disks from MBR to GPT. I have a 500GB SSD with my Windows 10 installation. I also have 2 1TB hard-drives with my personal files.

[Here are what my current partitions look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyLHC.png)

I know that you cannot have more than 3 partitions per drive for the conversion, but according to my layout, I don't.

[Here is what happens when I try to execute mbr2gpt /validate on the Windows 10 CMD.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAtEP.jpg) I accessed this CMD through the "Advanced Options" when holding Shift and pressing the Restart button on the Start menu.

The possible problem is that my boot partition is on Disk 1 (D: drive), while my Windows installation is on Disk 2 (C: drive). I was able to determine this through using a program called AOEMI Partition Assistant.

Comment: Why are you running mbr2gpt within Windows PE instead of Windows 10?  How did you end up with a single partition?  That isn't the default partition layout that the Windows installation environment uses.  Instead of submitting a comment clarify your question with the vital infomration required to answer your question.

Comment: I was running mbr2gpt with the CMD that can be accessed through the "Advanced Options" menu when you restart Windows while holding Shift. Also, what should my Windows partitions look like then?

Comment: By default, the Windows installation creates 3 partitions when MBR is used (Legacy Mode), which is the only way, to install MBR is to have Legacy Mode enabled.

Comment: That's so weird. I've confirmed that my disks are MBR, and by BIOS Mode is set to Legacy. I tried to convert my disks to GPT, but unfortunately I was given errors (as described in the post). Also somewhat relevant: When I was changing my boot configuration in the BIOS, I set my SSD to boot first and no OS showed up. I set my HDD to boot first and Windows 10 booted. However, Windows 10 is installed on my SSD? I'm not sure what to do :(

Comment: I would reinstall Windows 10 while in UEFI mode.  I would make sure you backup your personal files.

Comment: That seems like the move. Sounds a lot easier than this mess. Thank you for your help :)